# NodeJS Events module basic question about logging the events module

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

So basic question, I am learning Nodejs through a Mosh tutorial. He says that the EventEmitter a.k.a require('events') module is a class but when I console log it, it says that it is a function. Why is it? Also what is the use case of OS?

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events')
console.log(typeof EventEmitter)
console.log(EventEmitter)
```

Comment: Because all classes in javascript are of type Function. The function is the constructor

Answer (score 1):

`EventEmitter` behaves like a class.  You can use `new` with it.

`typeof` in Javascript reports `"function"` for the `typeof` of a class.  This is probably because Javascript doesn't have an official `class` type.  Instead, the `class` keyword is used by the interpreter to define a prototype, constructor and methods on that prototype.  The resulting object it creates is a constructor function that you use `new` with and thus the type of that resulting object is `"function"`.

You can run this little demo yourself to see:

```js
class foo {
    constructor() {

    }
}

console.log(typeof foo);
```

If you look internally at the [nodejs code for the events module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L75), you will see that `EventEmitter` is an older style constructor.  It does not use the `class` keyword.  Instead, it defines the constructor function and then manually adds properties to the prototype object.  This is exactly what the `class` keyword does for you and the two different types of syntax and code can create the same resulting class constructor.  It is likely done this way because this code predates the existence of the `class` keyword and either the maintainers want to remain compatible with older Javascript interpreters or nobody has found a reason to rewrite it using the newer syntax.